# Why does "Else" statement still print even if "IF" statement is true in nested for loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Why does my "ELSE" statement still prints even if my "IF" is always true

I have an array wherein I am trying to search to see if there is a substring in it. When it does have that substring it should run another for loop with if and elif statements

```
test = ['SCHEDULE:1457H', 'SCHEDULE:1550H', 'SCHEDULE:1740H', 'SCHEDULE:1705H']
task = ['ST:124', 'BROWSE:testB', 'DOWNLOAD:DLthis', 'REJECT:rejectme', 'APPROVE:goodtoGo', 'ST:123']

while time.time() < t_end:
    index = 0 
    for n in test:
        if "1457H" in n:
            for item in task:
                if "ST" in task[index]:
                    print(task[index])
                    index += 1
                    time.sleep(2)
                elif "LOGIN" in task[index]:
                    print(task[index])
                    index += 1
                elif "BROWSE" in task[index]:
                    print(task[index])
                    index += 1
                elif "DOWNLOAD" in task[index]:
                    print(task[index])
                    index += 1
                elif "REJECT" in task[index]:
                    print(task[index])
                    index += 1
                elif "APPROVE" in task[index]:
                    print(task[index])
                    index += 1

    else:  
        print("Sleeping")
        time.sleep(2)


Results:

ST:124
BROWSE:testB 
DOWNLOAD:DLthis 
REJECT:rejectme
APPROVE:goodtoGo
ST:123
Sleeping
```

Then repeats it again because of the while loop. I can't figure out why the "ELSE" statement still prints. I tried fixing the tab spaces of the "ELSE" statement and it still prints and even worse than the current Results.

Comment: In addition to the tabs/spaces issue (which is probably driving your main issue), your code has a lot of other very weird stuff going on. There's no good reason to be looping with `for item in task` if you're not going to use the `item` value at all, and instead use a manually updated `index`. If you really did need an index in addition to the value, you could use `enumerate` to get them both at the same time (`for index, item in enumerate(task):`).

Comment: Why did you remove an indent level in your post just now? I noticed already that you must have manually added spaces to format the block as code, and that the indentation you must be seeing in your editor wasn't *quite* reproducable from a simple remove-4-spaces operation here. Did you re-paste the code or manually remove those spaces?

Comment: I just need to print the value inside because I'm still gonna use that value as a variable to run another command. I just really need to make the "else" statement run properly. @Blckknght

Comment: @MartijnPieters copied it from sublime then pasted it here.

Comment: So you didn't add or remove indentation the first time you copied, or the second time you copied?

Comment: Either way, the code would not run *at all* as the current indentation in the post would raise an `IndentationError` exception; the `else:` block would end up at the wrong level for either the `for` or the `if` statements as far as Python is concerned.

Comment: I tried fixing it and the results are still the same @MartijnPieters but `else` should be aligned with first for loop right? cause if it is aligned with the `if "1457H" in n:` it prints `sleep` 3 times then executes the `if` in the next loop

Comment: @GanzoPalumi: so what did you expect to happen? The `else` block on a `for` is not influenced by `if` statements in the loop.

Comment: Hi, your else is not indented with if, your, hence, it is printing after coming out of for loop. Also, instead of using too many nested if and elif, use some other technique, which would also help in increasing your code readability

Answer (score 4):

You are mixing tabs and spaces in your code. *Do not do this*. Your editor is set to expand tabs to 4 spaces, while Python expands tabs to *8 spaces*. For your code, where some lines use tabs only, some lines use spaces only, and some lines appear to *mix* tabs and spaces, this leads to a completely different set of indented blocks as far as Python is concerned.

The `else` branch is indented to match the *`for` loop*, not the `if` test. This means the `else` block is always run when the `for` loop completes without a `break` statement, and not when the `if` test fails.

Configure your editor to use *spaces only* when indenting, and replace all tabs with 4 spaces, and your code will work fine.

Comment: I edited my post, the else statement should be aligned with the `for n in test:`  how do I make the "else" statement stop printing even if the "if" is true. I checked the spacing in sublime and nothings wrong with it

Comment: @GanzoPalumi: the text *as posted into your question* has loads wrong with it. Select the text in Sublime, and you'll see vague lines for tabs, dots for spaces. Use `View > Indentation > Tab width: 8` to see what Python sees. Then set the `Indent Using Spaces` and `Convert Indentation to Spaces` in the same submenu to repair (after switching back to a 4-character tab width).

Comment: @GanzoPalumi: then indent the `else` line to match the `if` indentation.

Comment: I matched it with `if "1457H" in n:` the result is still the same.

Comment: @GanzoPalumi: it is entirely unclear what you expect the `else` block to do. If paired with the `for` loop it will **always** be executed unless you exited the `for` loop with `break`.

Comment: I tried just putting one value inside the `test = [SCHEDULE: 1457H]` it prints fine. is it just because of my array or how I for loop it?

Comment: Without a clear description of what behaviour you are trying to code here I can't help, sorry.